# UIWebView - Download file with long non-direct link

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview, afnetworking

How would I be able to browse a UIWebView and clicking a download link, download the file. I can successfully detect direct links and download them using AFNetworking but not the long download site URL's like http://example.com/?file=ABCDEFGHIGH1245678996532&etc=foo.

I need this one last thing to finish my app. I don't really care about detecting one file type. I just want it to recognize a file download and download it.